Why does the iframe in my html page does not correctly display my live webcam feed?
I have a webpage up and running on localhost:5000 that I set up with node.js which is hosted by a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian OS.
I also have a USB webcam connected to the Raspberry Pi, which is working just fine after testing it with the cheese package and correctly getting the feed.
In my webpage's html file, I have an iframe element, which is setup like this:
<iframe src="http://localhost:5000/stream" height="200" width="300"</iframe>
My node.js server is handling the stream request of the webpage using the ffmpeg package like this:
// Handle video stream request
app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
    const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-f', 'v4l2',
        '-i', '/dev/video0',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-tune', 'zerolatency',
        '-f', 'flv',
        'http://localhost:5000/stream'
    ]);

    // Pipe ffmpeg output to HTTP response
    ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(res);

When I start my server, I see the ffmpeg command running in the terminal and capturing frames correctly, but I have no feed in the iframe, neither at the link http://localhost:5000/stream. The browser console also displays zero errors.
What could be the problem?

Try using the actual IP address, instead of localhost. This often fixes things with iframes.

Just tried this but unfortunately it did not work. Neither in the iframe, nor in :5000/stream.

The ffmpeg package would simply not work for me so I solved it by writing a Python script using Python's cv2 library and broadcasting the webcamera's feed to my webserver using Python's Flask framework.
